# Can't build Unreal Engine 4 project with Microsoft OpenXR plugin

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, hololens, unreal-blueprint, windows-mixed-reality

I am on on Unreal Engine 4.26.1. I am using Microsoft OpenXR 1.0. I have placed the plugin release files from https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft-OpenXR-Unreal/releases in the Plugins folder of my Unreal project folder. I am able to compile all project source code from within the editor successfully.

However, when I attempt to package my project, I get the following error:

```
LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   0.88ms
LogMainFrame: Selected target: HoloLensTest
LogLauncherProfile: Unable to use promoted target - ../../../../../../Users/sealfoss/Documents/Unreal Projects/HoloLensTest/Binaries/HoloLens/HoloLensTest.target does not exist.
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): Running AutomationTool...
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): Parsing command line: -ScriptsForProject="C:/Users/sealfoss/Documents/Unreal Projects/HoloLensTest/HoloLensTest.uproject" BuildCookRun -nocompileeditor -installed -nop4 -project="C:/Users/sealfoss/Documents/Unreal Projects/HoloLensTest/HoloLensTest.uproject" -cook -stage -archive -archivedirectory=C:/Users/sealfoss/Documents/
UnrealBuilds/HoloLensTest -package -ue4exe="C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Cmd.exe" -ddc=InstalledDerivedDataBackendGraph -pak -prereqs -nodebuginfo -targetplatform=HoloLens -build -target=HoloLensTest -clientconfig=Development -utf8output
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): Setting up ProjectParams for C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\HoloLensTest.uproject
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): ********** BUILD COMMAND STARTED **********
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): Running: C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe HoloLensTest HoloLens Development -Project="C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\HoloLensTest.uproject"  "C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\HoloLensTest.uproject" -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="C:\U
sers\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest" -Architecture=arm64 -Manifest="C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml" -NoHotReload -log="C:\Users\sealfoss\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\UBT-HoloLensTest-HoloLens-Development.txt"
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   Using ARM64 architecture for deploying to HoloLens device
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   Building using Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 for HoloLens
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   Writing manifest to C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   Building HoloLensTest...
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):   Building 2 actions with 32 processes...
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     [1/2] HoloLensTestarm64.exe
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(MixedRealityInterop.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(CameraImageCapture.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(AzureSpatialAnchors.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(SpatialAnchorHelper.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(HandMeshObserver.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(MeshObserver.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(SceneUnderstandingObserver.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     MixedRealityInteropHoloLens.lib(QRCodeObserver.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'C++/WinRT version': value '2.0.201113.7' doesn't match value '2.0.200729.8' in PCH.MicrosoftOpenXR.h.obj
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):        Creating library C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\Binaries\HoloLens\HoloLensTestarm64.lib and object C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\Binaries\HoloLens\HoloLensTestarm64.exp
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens):     C:\Users\sealfoss\Documents\Unreal Projects\HoloLensTest\Binaries\HoloLens\HoloLensTestarm64.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 8 mismatches detected
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): Took 7.6195669s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=6
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Users\sealfoss\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\UBT-HoloLensTest-HoloLens-Development.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
UATHelper: Packaging (HoloLens): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you try other solutions to the LNK2038 error, perform a clean build to ensure that the object files are current. If the issue still occurs, it is recommended that you update the Microsoft OpenXR Plugin to v1.1.0, because the new version of the packages.config file has been rewritten.

Comment: Thanks Hernando. I went into the project directory, deleted the Binaries, Build, DerivedDataCache, Intermediate, and Saved folders. I deleted my project's .sln file, and regenerated the visual studio project files. I replaced the MicrosoftOpenXR folder in my Plugins folder with the same from version 1.1.0. I was able to rebuild the project successfully. However, when I tried to package the project for HoloLens, I got the same errors.

Comment: It seems like something went wrong with your MixedRealtityInterop plugin, I found a similar problem in the unreal forum, the code deletion in 4.23 breaks the WMR plugin, and they got it working again by copying a few lines from the 4.22 branch: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/engine-source-github/1664397-failed-to-load-windows-mixed-reality-interop-library-ue-4-23?p=1665922#post1665922

Comment: There is an open issue on GitHub to report the similar problem:github.com/microsoft/Microsoft-OpenXR-Unreal/issues/12 It seems like WindowsMixedReality and OpenXR are incompatible with each other. Besides,  you are using OpenXR build 1.0  and can use 1.2 now. If the issue still occurs to you, it is recommended that you directly file an issue report to GitHub.